# Maximizing post oak bluff rate

Tags: betting-strategy, cash-game, post-oak-bluff

Apart from the ones mentioned by [Dan Harrington](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Post-oak_bluff), what are some situations in which post oak bluffs are most successful?

For example,

- against what kind of opponents
- against what kind of range we put the villain on
- on what kind of boards
- on what kind of history (if any) with the villain

I understand the answer might vary depending on the stakes but I'm thinking more generally here.

Comment: Follow the Dan Harrington link in original post for definition of post oak bluff and Dan Harrington's "ones mentioned".

Answer (score 2):

I think the play is weak and very difficult to be successful at. The main weakness in doing an oak bluff is that it is usually out of character for a strong player. It smells of tells, and anyone with a hand is going to call you, unless they are a weak passive paranoid player.

I kind of think any semblance of success with this bluff is not that one made a successful bluff, it is that the other opponents actually missed a draw of some kind.

However you asked so here is my best opinion.

•against what kind of opponents

Tight risk aversive opponents. You can spot this type by following Dan's guidelines. They are experienced player but not very good. They are the kind that is always whining about missing a hand. You can tell they have missed a hand easily and you should bet into them whenever it looks like they missed a flop, or river.

•against what kind of range we put the villain on

The opponent will have second pair or worse with a draw to a flush or straight. How your opponent sees you is more important, even very tight players will look up a loose cannon with second pair.

•on what kind of boards

Hard to say. Any board could qualify, that depends more on the players in the game and your specific opponent.

•on what kind of history (if any) with the villain

The opponent will be very tight, and proud of his great laydowns, may have shown some. Like DH says make sure it is someone that has laid down hands to small bets.

An oak bluff will not work against many players, it should really be something that is simply the obvious thing to do when you do it.